# Azure Automation calling an interal application Rest API on a Hybrid Worker returning a 400 error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I'm trying to build an Azure Automation Runbook to unlock an on-prem AD Account. Once the account is unlocked I want to submit a ticket to our ITSM application that has an API. I am able to create the call on the server in Windows PowerShell and get a return code of 200.

However when I run it from Azure Automation I receive an error code of 400 bad request. Any thoughts as to why I can make the call on the Server with Windows PowerShell but not Azure Automation on the Hybrid Worker?

The module for the Custom_ITSM_API_Module was a homegrown module and works every where I have tried it. It works on my development computer (Windows PowerShell) and on the hybrid worker server (Windows PowerShell) but not when using Azure Automation.

Code:

```
Param
([object]$WebhookData) #this parameter name needs to be called WebHookData otherwise the webhook does not work as expected.
$VerbosePreference = 'continue'

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module "Custom_ITSM_API_Module"

#region Verify if Runbook is started from Webhook.

# If runbook was called from Webhook, WebhookData will not be null.
if ($WebHookData){

# Collect properties of WebhookData
$WebhookName     =     $WebHookData.WebhookName
$WebhookHeaders  =     $WebHookData.RequestHeader
$WebhookBody     =     $WebHookData.RequestBody

# Collect individual headers. Input converted from JSON.
$From = $WebhookHeaders.From
$RequestData = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookBody)
Write-Output -InputObject ('Input: {0}' -f $RequestData )
Write-Output ('WebhookBody: {0}' -f $WebhookBody)
Write-Output -InputObject ('Runbook started from webhook {0} by {1}.' -f $WebhookName, $From)

$User = Get-ADUser $RequestData.SamAccountName -Properties *
If($User.SamAccountName.count -ne 1 ){
throw "Found $($User.SamAccountName.count) user(s). Please make sure this user is unique"
}
else{
    Write-Output "Unlocking User"
    Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $User

    $RanByEmployeeID = $RequestData.RanByEmployeeID
    $Runby = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeID -eq $RanByEmployeeID} -Properties EmployeeID
    $Description = "User Unlcoked<br>EmployeeID: $($User.EmployeeID)<br>SamAccountName: $($User.SamAccountName)<br>Unlocked at: $((Get-Date).ToString())"
    Write-Custom_ITSM_API_ModuleTicket -Title "Unlocked User $($User.Name)"-Description $Description

  }
}
else{
   Write-Error -Message 'Runbook was not started from Webhook' -ErrorAction stop
}
```

Comment: What service account did you configure for the hybrid worker? No where in your code do you handle credentials. A simple `whoami | out-file "c:\temp\res.txt"` could be helpful.

Comment: In the azure hybrid worker with a webhook I can specify what credentials are used  by default when I set up the hybrid worker to run without specifying in the code. The "Custom_ITSM_API_Module" has a connection to receive credentials from within the module

Comment: I did use whoami and it is running under the service account I expected

Comment: For us to help you, you need to share either some screen shots and some real output. Both things should be sanitized, so you don't reveal any sensitive information. Please update the question with the new details and I'll be happy to assist you with troubleshooting it. An idea would be to create new runbook that is simple and just have it output some system information. Then we know that the runbook and hybrid worker is working like expected.

Comment: Hi  Mötz, 
This is the real script I am trying to run. I can provide that I have tried to hit other APIs and I am getting the same 400 error message. 

I have even tried just hitting an endpoint in rightfax to test a different api. Ill post screen shots with this sanitized 


$MyCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('MyTestUser', 'Password')

(Invoke-RestMethod -uri "http://servername/RightFax/API/users?find=MyTestUser" -Method Get -Credential $MyCreds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was actually an issue with our firewall and proxy. These servers were not able to speak to all of the Azure/O365 URLS that were suggested. Once we had all of the URLS white-listed I was able to speak to my internal applications.